# Filtering out all date hours past a point with regex for Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

So I want to send a filter with the query I am sending to Google Analytics, in a way that I will only get results back which are *younger* than a given day and hour

For example I would want to get all the results after 2013-03-12-15 (YYYY-MM-DD-HH)

My problem is in how to phrase the regex so that I will not miss out any records

Comment: Why a  regular expression ? "Greater  than (hour of day)" seems to work nicely (and even if it weren't you could use "greater than (index hour)").

Comment: With google analytics you specify to dates as your start and end date for the query, however if you want to only get results past a certain hour of the day you must add a filter, i am filtering by a property called ga:dateHour, which google classifies as a dimension and for some reason they do not allow you to use greater than operators, only regex.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was me being stupid (date and time are dimensions, hence you cannot use mathematical operators with them in the API).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, despite my wrong comment I still think this is easier to solve with the use of index hour (than ga:dateHour), which is ga:nthHour in the API.

Index hour is given as a string of 6 numbers left-padded with zeros (first hour is 000000, second is 000001 etc). To get all results after 2013-03-12-15 you set 2013-03-12 as start date and filter out any results with an index hour after 15 (or after 14 if you want 15 included).

You still need a regular expression, but that is (IMO) much easier to construct (than an expression that parses a date) . My first try would be

Filter `ga:nthHour!~00001[0-5]|00000[0-9]`

where 00001[0-5] filters out index hours ten to 15 and 00000[0-9] filter index hour zero to nine (I'm sure this can be done more elegantly). I tested this in the query explorer and am reasonably sure it returns the desired result.